# Async replication between 2 mariadb galera clusters

Tags: mysql, cluster-computing, replication, galera

I have 2 mariadb galera clusters having 3 nodes each. I want to achieve async replication between them(master slave).
What would be the parameters that needs to be configured in all 6 nodes. As per my understanding we can achieve this with help of GTID. Request your suggestions on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please note that Galera's GTIDs are different than MySQL's.  I assume that all 6 servers are running MariaDB+Galera?

Comment: I have heard of having _one_ node on one cluster acting as Master to _one_ node in the other cluster.  Will that suffice?  That setup is essentially the regular M-S setup.